# Override API url in environment.ts with API value from K8S manifest "env:"

Tags: angular, kubernetes

I would like to know if it's possible to override a value in environment.ts files (angular) with a Kubernetes manifest?

I do it for application.properties (spring) but looks like it's not working the same way with Angular.

here's what I do for Spring :

```
spec:
            containers:
                - name: $(appName)
                  image: ACR/$(image)
                  imagePullPolicy: 
                  ports:
                    - name: http
                      containerPort: 8080
                      protocol: TCP
                  env:
                    - name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
                      value: "$(datasourcePassword)"
```

and the value of the password changes based on what I set for $(datasourcePassword) variable (azure devops variable). If I put a fake password API cannot access DB.

But if I do the same with the manifest I use for Angular :

```
spec:
            containers:
                - name: $(appName)
                  image: ACR/$(image)
                  imagePullPolicy: 
                  ports:
                    - name: http
                      containerPort: 8181
                      protocol: TCP
                  env:
                    - name: APIENDPOINT
                      value: "$(APIurl)"
```

the front still use the value defined by default in the environment.ts :

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  APIEndpoint: 'http://localhost:8080'
};
```

where am I doing it wrong?

thanks a lot for the help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced the same issue you described.
A good way I found to solve it, was creating an environment-service-loader where I do a merge between the properties from an env.json file and the properties defined in the environment.ts.

Let me describe each step.

**ANGULAR**

**1. Create in the app.module.ts the two following providers**

```
    import {environment} from '../environments/environment';

    function initEnvironmentServiceFactory(
      envServiceLoader: EnvServiceLoader,
      environmentService: EnvironmentService
    ) {
     return async () => {
       const envs = await envServiceLoader.loadEnvVariables();
       environmentService.setEnvVariables(envs);
     };
    }

    providers: [
      ....
      {provide: 'environment_prod', useValue: environment},
      {
        provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
        useFactory: initEnvironmentServiceFactory,
        deps: [EnvServiceLoader, EnvironmentService],
        multi: true
      },
      ....
```

**2. Create the EnvServiceLoader that will "override" the environment.ts and the properties defined in env.json file under assets/json. In this example I defined the key production as uneditable.**

```
    @Injectable({
     providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class EnvServiceLoader {

      UNEDITABLE_PROPERTIES = ['production'];

      constructor(@Inject('environment_prod') private environment, private 
        httpClient: HttpClient) {
      }

      async loadEnvVariables(): Promise<any> {
        const envJson = await this.getJsonConfig();
        return {...this.environment, ...envJson, ...this.getUneditableConfig(this.environment)};
      };

      private getJsonConfig(): Promise<any> {
        return this.httpClient.get('./assets/json/env.json')
          .pipe(map((res: string) => JSON.parse(res)),
            catchError(() => of({})
            )).toPromise();
      }

      private getUneditableConfig(environmentConfig: any) {
        return this.UNEDITABLE_PROPERTIES.reduce((config, key) => {
          config[key] = environmentConfig[key];
          return config;
        }, {});
      };
    }
```

**3. Create the EnvironmentService**

```
   @Injectable({
      providedIn: 'root'
   })
   export class EnvironmentService {
      private env;

      setEnvVariables(env): void {
        this.env = env;
      }

      getEnvVariables(): any {
        return this.env;
      }
    }
```

**KUBERNETES**

**1. Create a **configmap** in Kuberentes containing the value you want to override through the env.json**

```
  apiVersion: v1
  kind: ConfigMap
  metadata:
    name: client-config
  data:
    env.json: |
      "{\"API_endpoint\": \"http://localhost:8080\"}
```

**2. In your Kubernetes Deployment for your client through a volume (named config-volume in this example) you can copy the content of your configmap into the the file env.json under /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/json.**

```
  containers:
  - image: your_client_image
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: your_client
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
      name: http
    volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /usr/share/nginx/html/assets/json
        name: config-volume
  volumes:
  - configMap:
      name: client-config
    name: config-volume
```